# Specific conductance of 0.1 M acetic acid

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, conductivity

> Find specific conductance of $\pu{0.1 M}$ acetic acid given that its molar conductivity is $\pu{4.6 S cm^2 mol^-1}$.

I used the formula $\Lambda_\mathrm m = \kappa/c$, where $\Lambda_\mathrm m$ is the molar conductivity, $\kappa$ is the specific conductance and $c$ is the concentration of the electrolyte in $\pu{mol/L}$.

What's confusing me is the value of $c$. At first I thought it should be the given molarity, but according to my text book $c$ is the concentration of the *electrolyte*. Now the acetic acid molecule does not conduct electricity, rather its constituent ions do. So shouldn't the value of $c$ be the concentration of its ions which turns out to be $\pu{\sqrt{1.8} \times 10^{-3} mol/L}$ (using the equation of the acidic dissociation of acetic acid)?

Also the answer given was $\pu{4.6E-4 S cm^-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

With the data provided with your problem I suspect you are only supposed to carefully use provided formula with the corresponding units of measurements. You need to convert the concentration from $\pu{mol L^-1}$ to $\pu{mol  cm^-3}$ considering $\pu{1 L} = \pu{10^3 cm^3}$:

$$\kappa = \Lambda_\mathrm m c = (\pu{4.6 S cm^2 mol^-1})(\pu{0.1E-3 mol cm^-3}) = \pu{4.6E-4 S cm^-1}$$

Comment: So is my reasoning correct, that is, should 'c' actually be substituted as (sqrt 1.8) x 10^-3?

Comment: @Azulene No, I have no idea where this  (sqrt 1.8) x 10^-3 value comes from. I used $\pu{0.1 M}$. You are given neither the dissociation constant of acetic acid, nor the temperature. And please get to know [how to use LaTeX for proper formatting of math and chemical equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).